# How to check if a Dataframe contains a list or dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe :

```
col1   col2   col3       col4   
A     11    [{'id':2}]    {"price": 0.0}
B     21    [{'id':3}]    {"price": 2.0}
C     31    [{'id':4}]    {"price": 3.0}
```

I want to find out what all columns are of datatype 'list' and 'dictionary' and probably store the result into another list. 
How do i go about it ?

when i use this :
`data.applymap(type).apply(pd.value_counts)`
output is :

```
col1  col2        col3            col4
0    a    11  [{'id':2}]  {"price": 0.0}
1    b    21  [{'id':3}]  {"price": 2.0}
2    c    31  [{'id':4}]  {"price": 3.0}
```

Comment: Does something like: `df.applymap(type).apply(pd.value_counts)` get you close?

Comment: Nothing happens..It just outputs the same dataframe

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: have your column dict and list or only str?

Comment: @Anti_cse51 err... that definitely won't return the same DF...? Could you [edit] your Q to show what the output of the above is given your input? It's not clear if you've just got strings that need interpreting or whether you've actually got list/dict objects.

Comment: @JonClements:expected output probably be a list L = ['list':col2,'dict':col4]..or something like that..

Comment: @ansev : col1 is str, col2 is int,col3 is list, col4 is dict..

Comment: Okay... so using the code I put in a comment - can you [edit] to show the output of that? You'll get an index of the column names and then columns of the count of types that column contains... Then we can probably tweak that accordingy...

Comment: @JonClements : output is still the same ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC,

we can use `apply` and `literal_eval` from the ast standard library to build up a dictionary:

for performance reasons, lets work with the first row of the data frame as `apply` is computationally quite heavy.

```
from ast import literal_eval
data_dict = {}
for col in df.columns:
    try:
        col_type = df[col].iloc[:1].apply(literal_eval).apply(type)[0]
        data_dict[col] = col_type
    except (ValueError,SyntaxError):
        data_dict[col] = 'unable to evaluate'

print(data_dict)
```

---

```
{'col1': 'unable to evaluate',
 'col2': 'unable to evaluate',
 'col3': list,
 'col4': dict}
```

Comment: does not work for datetype object ? 

Error :2020-03-08T14:10:23Z
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid token

Comment: @Anti_cse51 there is no datetime in your example?

Comment: Sorry @Datanovice : I forgot to add datatime column. Rookie mistake .

Comment: @Anti_cse51 see edit, you just need to handle the multiple exceptions.